# Libgeos packages Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: 18.04, package-management, compiling

Providing an Ubuntu Bionic server with R-Studio running on it, we need to have some geographical packages, in the case of my question libgeos. I created a problem and hopefully here I can find a solution.
Default libgeos package on Bionic is version 3.6.2 and knows a lot of dependencies with other packages like for example gdal. A while ago I needed a test with a newer version and I installed version 3.7.0rc1 compiled from source which gave good results in the past year. installing via apt was not possible yet at that moment.
Last week trying to run some functionality in R-Studio an error occurred that this geos version v3.7.0rc1 is not supported (anymore?).
I tried updating the geos package but got the message that a version 3.7.1 (?) is already installed.
Installing version 3.6.2 (which wasn't there anymore?) went well but gave havoc in R-Studio (multiple geos packages next to each other) and checking geos-config in /usr/local/bin and /opt/geos-3.7.0rc1/tools/ both keeps showing version v3.7.0rc1.

I am a bit confused now and a few questions arose:

- Do I have to stick to compiling from source now or can I go back to normal installations of geos packages (apt)?
- Is there a possibility to let Ubuntu know that this apt-installed version 3.7.1 is the one to use instead of the compiled version 3.7.0rc1?
- Why was the geos-config file not manipulated in both locations when installing an other version than v3.7.0rc1?

Thanks in advance for thinking along and kind regards,

Aad

Comment: You can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 for libgeos 3.8, and 22.04 (to be released this April) for version 3.10 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgeos

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think that will be the best way to handle this issue.